# How to create a list in a new column when data in another column is > ..% with the conditional formatting included?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheets project with a table in there. The cells percentages change every now and then (external API kind of add-on) and I would like the column to be checked if a certain percentage is met. If it is, the corresponding name in column A should be copied in column D let's say. So example:

A formula something like: if a value of column C > 5%, copy the corresponding name in column A to a new column D. But the main thing is that it shifts everything up so there are no gaps. If I refresh the data, it should create the list again with no gaps and remove the former data that doesn't meet the requirements anymore. Please help!

P.S. I would also like the background color of column C (conditional) to copy to the new column

Comment: Consider posting some screenshots to illustrate what you are trying to do. Also, consider splitting this into two separate questions.

Comment: [image](https://imgur.com/a/p5Dvakv) This is an image of what I want to have. The info in column G should be copied to column I if it is more than or equal to 8%. It should shift it all up in column I so there are no empty gaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `QUERY`

```
=QUERY(A2:A, "where A > 0.05")
```

[image: 0]

and then all you need to do is select **Greater then** in CF rules:

[image: 0]

Comment: Already have that, but I mean especially the copying of cells that have a certain requirement.